# Set parent or child of a control programmatically

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error, parent

I'm trying to set the parent of a control in access VBA programmatically by using `Me.MyControl.Parent`, but I keep getting the run time error:

> 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Is there a way to set the parent of a control in access programmatically?

Comment: The parent of `MyControl` appears to be `Me`. So why don't you just use `Me`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'set the parent'? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to change the parent of MyControl, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: For example in javascript you can set the parent or the child of an object programatically, is it possible to do that in in access with vba?

Comment: can you show the full line of code generating the error?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem, I thought that there was a DOM hierarchy in access just like in javascript which would have allowed me to assign a parent or child to any controls.

I had a bunch of labels that I named `box1,box2,...box42` and I wanted another label to appear on top of the numbered labels when the cursor is hovering on them.

My solution as of now is to have all the labels present but invisible. When I hover on the box, I simply turn the current label to visible using the box number. `Ex: Box1 -> lb1, Box2 -> lb2, etc.`

```
Me.Controls("lb" & boxNum).Visible = True
```

Comment: Here's info on the [Parent Property in Access 2003](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa173191(v=office.11).aspx), might be a good read for you,  By the way, "***Welcome to Stack Overflow***!"  I'm glad you figured this one out; for your "next" question, check out "[mcve]"  and also "[help/on-topic]", as well as some *great* [tips here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question) which will help others help you...  :-)